# How to set new variable if the IF statement returns true?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I have a batch code which creates certain variables. However, I want to add an `IF` statement so that if the user enters "Technology" for the first variable, it then creates another variable and asks for additional information. A python script then reads these variables for further processing.

Here is the code:

```
set constraint_type=1
set constraint_technology=1

set /p constraint_type="Enter constraint type (E.g. "Equipment" or "Technology"): "
IF /I !constraint_type!=="Technology" set /p constraint_technology="Enter Technology name: "

cmd /k python "script.py" %constraint_type% %constraint_technology% 
@echo on
```

The code runs but the user isn't prompted for the `constraint_technology` variable. Am I missing something?

Comment: `IF /I !constraint_type!=="Technology"` --> `IF /I "%constraint_type%"=="Technology"` (normal `%` expansion, and quotes to avoid trouble with empty entry)

Comment: @aschipfl - Awesome, thanks for the tip ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably did not enable delayed expansion

`!constraint_type!` wouldn't evaluate without it. Also remove the quotes, because batch won't do it, so comparison will always be false since user won't put quotes in the input.

even better fix: use standard env. var delimiters, works in all cases,

```
IF /I %constraint_type%==Technology
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the issue still remains.

Comment: You're absolutely right, works great now. Many thanks for your answer :)